# Anaconda conda traceback: UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xb9 in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, python-2.7, anaconda, conda

OS: `WIN7 64bit`

Anaconda version: 4.4.0 of `Python 2.7`

After the installation, I typed "conda" in cmd while it showed the error as below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Anaconda2\Scripts\conda-script.py", line 5, in <module>
    sys.exit(conda.cli.main())
……
……
  File "D:\Anaconda2\lib\ntpath.py", line 85, in join
    result_path = result_path + p_path
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xb9 in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I installed my Anaconda at the root of `D:\`, so I think there is no illegal character would exist.

How to fix this `UnicodeDecodeError`?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
import sys
if sys.getdefaultencoding() != 'gbk':  
reload(sys)  
sys.setdefaultencoding('gbk')      
import conda.cli
sys.exit(conda.cli.main())
```

please change conda-scripts.py to above code

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been solved by inserting the following codes into **conda-script.py**:

```
if sys.getdefaultencoding() != 'gbk':  
reload(sys)  
sys.setdefaultencoding('gbk')
```